# Retrieving Full Name in Apple Sign In After Account Deletion?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, sign-in-with-apple

In my app, users can log in using their Apple ID, which provides necessary details like tokens and the user's full name upon initial login. However, if a user or admin deletes the account and later attempts to sign in again with Apple ID, the full name may appear as null. To resolve this, the user currently needs to navigate to "Settings" > "Sign in & Security" > "Sign in with Apple" > "Your App" > "Stop Using Apple ID,"
which is not practical for the app. Is there a way to retrieve the full name in Apple Sign In after the first use or achieve the above steps programmatically? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If the account is deleted then you should reject the login with an appropriate message; at that point they need to follow the steps you listed to remove the Sign in with Apple link and they can sign in again, creating a new account. Alternatively you can recreate the empty account and provide an ability for the user to update their name etc in your app

Comment: Yes admin remove the account then we can reject the login. But if user decide to delete the account and later he decide to join again. i think there must be a way to do that programatically? Without creating account with null name

Comment: If they deleted their account then they need to live with the consequences of that. Show them a message that the account is deleted and provide a link to [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426)